# Centralizar duas divs com texto

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

HTML

```
<div class="contatoTopo">
  <div class="buscaConteudoCent">           
    <div class="buscaFontEncontraTit">Nenhum resultado encontrado para:</div>
    <div class="buscaFontEncontra">"teste"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .contatoTopo{
      background-image: url('../imagens/contatoBG.jpg');
      background-repeat: repeat;
      height: 176px;
      line-height: 176px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
  }
.buscaConteudoCent {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
}
.buscaFontEncontraTit {
  font-family: 'ubuntulight_italic';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}
.buscaFontEncontra {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'ubuntubold_italic';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

O que está acontecendo, ele não está centralizando as duas divs com os textos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A palavra 'teste' é um exemplo, virá do sistema e poderá ser maior, por isso não consigo centralizar.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entenda que se você não definir uma largura para o div e definir como `float: left;`, ele ficará do tamanho do seu conteudo, logo não tem como centralizar se não há espaço sobrando para isso...

Outro problema é que ao definir o `float: left;` este tem uma certa prioridade ao `text-align: center;`, um não se da muito bem com o outro...

coloque a palavra chave dentro do div, em um span (que é in-line por natureza) para definir a classe, e retire os floats.

**CSS**

```
 .contatoTopo{
      background-image: url('../imagens/contatoBG.jpg');
      background-repeat: repeat;
      height: 176px;
      line-height: 176px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
  }
.buscaConteudoCent {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
}
.buscaFontEncontraTit {
  font-family: 'ubuntulight_italic';
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.buscaFontEncontra {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'ubuntubold_italic';
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="contatoTopo">
  <div class="buscaConteudoCent">           
    <div class="buscaFontEncontraTit">Nenhum resultado encontrado para: <span class="buscaFontEncontra">"teste"</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```